# How to use loops (i.e., for loop) with diagrams and graphviz in Python

Tags: python, graphviz, diagram

greetings!

Please, can you guide how to use a `for` loop with Python Diagram?

Original sample code without any loop is as follow

```
from diagrams import Cluster, Diagram, Edge
from diagrams import Diagram
from diagrams.aws.compute import EC2
from diagrams.aws.database import RDS
from diagrams aws.network import ELB

with Diagram("Diagram", show= True, direction="TB"):
    ELB("") >> Edge(color="red", label="Traffic") >> \
    [EC2("Instance1"),EC2("Instance2"),EC2("Instance3")]
```

Following code gives error. However expectation is to use a `for` loop:

```
from diagrams import Cluster, Diagram, Edge
from diagrams import Diagram
from diagrams.aws.compute import EC2
from diagrams.aws.database import RDS
from diagrams aws.network import ELB

instances = ["Instance1", "Instance2", "Instance3"]

with Diagram("Diagram", show= True, direction="TB"):
    ELB("") >> Edge(color="red", label="Traffic") >> \
    for instance in instances:
        EC2(instance)
```

I have tried to use a loop, instead of hardcoded logic. It gives error. This requires to install `graphviz` and `diagrams`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [examples](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/docs/getting-started/examples) page, something like this should work:

```
from diagrams import Cluster, Diagram, Edge
from diagrams import Diagram
from diagrams.aws.compute import EC2
from diagrams.aws.database import RDS
from diagrams aws.network import ELB

instances = ["Instance1", "Instance2", "Instance3"]

with Diagram("Diagram", show= True, direction="TB"):
    ELB("") >> Edge(color="red", label="Traffic") >> [EC2(instance) for instance in instances]
```